How to put dataframe results in different sheets of an excel and store it in own DBFS folder in databrciks
Is there a way to put two different dataframe results in one csv file and store it in own databrikcs folder.
so basically I have DF1(Result set) and DF2(count of results) and i want to keep both the dataframe output in two different sheets in csv and finaly save it in my own databricks folder in DBFS.
I have sample code which i use it to store the dataframe results in csv in my own databrciks folder.
output_file = '/dbfs/FileStore/xyz/abc.csv'
print(output_file)
print(df_count.shape)
df_count.to_csv(output_file, index = None, header=True)


I have tried the below approach using Pandas:
import os
dbfs_directory = '/FileStore/tables/D01'
if not os.path.exists(dbfs_directory):
    os.makedirs(dbfs_directory)
output_file = dbfs_directory + 'abc.xlsx'
df1_pd = df1.toPandas()
df2_pd = df2.toPandas()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file)
df1_pd.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DF1', index=False)
df2_pd.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DF2', index=False)
writer.save()

# Results:

df1_read = pd.read_excel(output_file, sheet_name='DF1')
df2_read = pd.read_excel(output_file, sheet_name='DF2')
print("Data for Sheet 1 (DF1):")
print(df1_read)
print("\nData for Sheet 2 (DF2):")
print(df2_read)

'''
Data for Sheet 1 (DF1):
   Name  Age      City
0  John   25  New York
1  Kate   30    London
2  Mike   35     Paris

Data for Sheet 2 (DF2):
       City  Count
0  New York    100
1    London    200
2     Paris    300
'''

Additionally, I have written the Excel file to ADLS to check if I can see the DF1 and DF2 in spreadsheets.


In the above code, I am importing libraries, defining a directory path in the Databricks FileStore, and checking if the directory exists. If the directory does not exist, it is created using os.makedirs().
The directory path is then combined with the desired output file name (abc.xlsx) to create the full file path for saving the Excel file.
Next, the PySpark DataFrames (df1 and df2) are converted to Pandas DataFrames. These DataFrames are then written to an Excel file (abc.xlsx) under different sheet names ('DF1' and 'DF2').
This process involves checking and creating a directory, preparing the output file path, converting data to Pandas format, and finally, writing the data to an Excel file.
